# Remove site map entry in project

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to remove an existing site map with a customization project similar to adding one, or do we need to do a customization plugin to delete it?

Update:

I have been trying the solution below, but I keep getting errors.  I searched for sitemap maintenance in the code and found a routine in the wizard logic, but it won't work in my code.  I checked all the includes and I have everything I need.

The select below shows an error stating "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'PXSelectBase.Select(params object[])'"

```
using Customization;
using PX.Data;
using PX.SM;
using System;    

...

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete site map entry
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="screenID">Sitemap screen ID</param>
    protected virtual void DeleteSiteMap(string screenID)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(screenID))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("screenID");
        }
        SiteMap sitemap = PXSelect<SiteMap, Where<SiteMap.screenID, Equal<Required<SiteMap.screenID>>>>
            .Select(this, screenID);
        return;
        // Edit:
        // starting 2017R2 there could be MUI* tables witch references to the sitemap. These are the new workspaces. 
        // It would be a good idea to check these tables for reference to the deleting screen. This script was written in 6.1 which did not have the modern UI workspaces.
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I have done this in the past was to use a [customization plugin](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=3ef5784b-1602-4a04-b6b9-52b69c79fe91). You can query the sitemap table by screen id and delete it if found.

Something like this should work (although I have not tested this). I did pull some of it from our upgrade plugin for a quick sample:

```
protected virtual void RemoveSiteMapEntry(PXGraph graph, string screenId)
{
    PX.SM.SiteMap siteMap = PXSelect<PX.SM.SiteMap,
        Where<PX.SM.SiteMap.screenID, Equal<Required<PX.SM.SiteMap.screenID>>>>.Select(graph, screenId);

    if (siteMap == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    graph.Caches[typeof(PX.SM.SiteMap)].PersistDeleted(siteMap);

    // Edit:
    // starting 2017R2 there could be MUI* tables witch references to the sitemap. These are the new workspaces. 
    // It would be a good idea to check these tables for reference to the deleting screen. This script was written in 6.1 which did not have the modern UI workspaces.
}
```

Alternatively you could write a `PXDatabase.Delete` statement without the need of a `PXGraph`. I only use `PXDatabase` for upgrade logic or bulk processing of records when necessary.

All of these options you could call from a Customization Plugin. For a Graph you need to create a new instance before you can use it for my example.

Comment: To my knowledge this is still the way to do it in 2017+ Acumatica versions. Additionally for a more thorough cleanup you can delete the entry in the tables prefixed MUI which are used for the new UI in Acumatica 2017+.

Comment: Good point @HB_ACUMATICA. My upgrade script that performed this was in version 6.1. Make sure you remove any workspace that contains this screen ID also starting with 2017 or greater. As pointed out these tables start with MUI. The best solution might be to use the sitemap graph and delete from there as (I assume) it will automatically handle the relational deletes to the MUI tables.

Comment: If someone has an example deleting the sitemap using the sitemap graph that would be a nice answer for 2017R2+ as long as it removes the MUI* table entries too.

Comment: Brendan, see my update to the question above.  I am trying to select the SiteMap, but I get an error.  I am mirroring code I found in WZSetupMaint.cs

Comment: My guess on your error is you are not passing in a graph as the first parameter to PXSelect<>.Select(this). Are you in a new graph? Otherwise if you are in a graph extension you use "Base" as your graph like PXSelect<...>.Select(Base, ...)

Comment: That was it.  I am used to sending "this" as the graph on pxselects but running as a plugin must require the specific graph.

Comment: yes a plugin is not a graph so you need to create an instance of a graph and pass that in your select. Glad that worked.